# Git push to GitHub failing - seems to be trying to use HTTP?

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, hudson, github

I've setup a Hudson continuous intgration server on an Ubuntu 8.04 slice, git version 1.6.4. I am able to have it pull code from a private repo GitHub, but I can't seem to get it to push the tags back after a build. I see the following:

```
# sudo -u hudson git push --tags
XML error: syntax error
error: Error: no DAV locking support on https://github.com/dealbase/dealbase/
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/dealbase/dealbase'
```

If I do "ssh -v git@github.com" from the hudson user, I can successfully authenticate to GitHub (which makes sense as well given I can pull/clone from a private repo). My impression is that this git push is trying to use WebDAV/run over HTTP or something when doing the push? My .gitconfig is the same as another user on the system (my regular, non-hudson user) which can successfully push tags.

Comment: It does look like it's trying to use http. What's the form of the URL given for `origin` in your `.git/config`? If it starts with `http://` (or `https://`) that's your problem - you want a `git://` address. Note that if you create the repo by cloning, this address is copied from what you clone from - it's easy to accidentally use `http` instead of `git` during the clone and not realize you've done something permanent.

Comment: Jefromi, thanks, I believe that was it, it started with https, instead of git.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to edit your `.git/config` file by hand (or are scared of messing it up), you can use the `git remote` commands to edit your remote repository list.

`git remote show` will list the remote repositories that your local repository knows about, and `git remote show <reponame>` will show the specifics of that given repo (like the push URL). You can `git remote rm <reponame>` and `git remote add <reponame> <repourl>` to reset it to your github ssh URL.

Comment: Or `git remote set-url <reponame> <repourl>` to change it without deleting-recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `.git/config` (not `~/.gitconfig`) `remote` section and make sure it has proper url value.