# Issue with Tuleap GIt plugin

Tags: git, gitolite, tuleap

A project has been created in tuleap with git enabled. and with the repository created for tuleap we are able to git clone, add and commit changes. When we try to push the changes to the remote via http, it throws an error as no Dav locking support enabled for repository url. Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to switch to an ssh url of your gitolite server on Tuleap ([see the comments on my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9243773/6309))

Checking the gitolite logs on the server can help. [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitolite/q0pXJiO3pNw) illustrates that any kind on gitolite redirection ([mirror or slave](http://documentation-tuleap.readthedocs.org/en/latest/administration-guide/howto.html#deploy-git-mirroring) to actual gitolite master server) would not support http.

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://gitolite@<server_name>
```