# Unable to push or publish any changes on GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push, repo

I am getting following error while pushing or publishing a new branch on GitLab repo. Although, i am able to perform other git commands without any errors.

XML error: mismatched tag
error: no DAV locking support on https://repo.company.com/projetc/project2.0.git/
fatal: git-http-push failed

Please help.

1. I tried reinstalling Git
2. Cloned project into new folder and tried to create new test branch but still same issue

Comment: Looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72906920/2437508

Comment: tried that, it didn't work